# error - html autoplay embedded video not working

Tags: html, vimeo-player

I am trying to embed a video and i want it to autoplay when the page loads. I have used the  tag and have added &autoplay=1 to the end of my source but it isn't working.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried replacing &autoplay=1 with true instead of 1 and numerous other ways, when the page loads it just says Oops the url is incorrect.

Comment: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729&autoplay=1` to `https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729?autoplay=1`.. This will work.. You should start adding parameter by using `?` and append the next parameters with `&`..

Answer (score 2):

Used  bellow iframe code. Error in video URL Replace this URL

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729&autoplay=1
```

TO

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729?autoplay=1

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this brother

`https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729&autoplay=1`

into this

`https://player.vimeo.com/video/91310729?autoplay=1`